# What is the meaning of the the statement , "cpu generates memory address or a program generates memory addresses"?

Tags: operating-system

How can CPU generate a memory address, address to memory cells are defined before itself so what is the meaning of that , cpu generates a memory address??

Comment: How can a program generate a memory address?

Comment: (It would help if you told us where you're reading this, to provide context.)

Comment: i am reading this in galvin operating system concepts.

Comment: For a book that costs $118, I'd hope the book explains that.

Answer (score 0):

From the context you  gave above, it appears that you are trying to understand memory management concepts in OS. Galvin is a great source by the way, but I would agree there are confusing statements as the above at quite a few places in Galvin.

Nevertheless, to your question, I will try to give an idea of my understanding about it:

**CPU Generates Memory Address** -

So OS needs to make sure that all the processes run in their own address space and do not illegally try to access the address space of another process or the OS itself.

To do this the OS makes use of the Base register and Limit register. These registers can be accessed and modified only by the OS through special instructions. These special instructions can be executed only by the OS, because the OS runs in the kernel mode. User programs, since they run in user mode, so they can not access these registers and hence can not modify the value of the Base and Limit registers.

Now consider a situation where you have written a program, that has been compiled and it's exe (binary or rather put, an instance of this above program - a process) is residing in the input queue, ready to be brought into the main memory to be taken up by the CPU for execution. So the OS will make sure that this process gets loaded only in the address space allotted to it.

So far all good. Now lets say that one of the instructions in the process (that is now in the memory, in it's own address space) needs to access some data from some memory location. When the CPU takes this instruction for execution (in it's instruction cycle, Fetch-Decode-Execute) it sees that for the completion of the execution of this instruction, the CPU needs to access some data from some other memory location.

**This memory location, as mentioned in the instruction, is not an actual physical address. It is rather  a relocatable address. The linker/loader converts this address to an absolute address. The CPU translates (or let's call it as GENERATES) this address to a logical address. (The OS takes care of converting this logical address, generated by the CPU, to actual physical address, on one of the memory banks. This translation is actually done by the MMU - hardware)**

> This is my understanding of the phrase "CPU Generates a memory address"